# How can I specify character-encoding on liquibase sql for oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, character-encoding, maven-3, liquibase

I created `insert` scripts in an oracle database by liquibase.

But I have a problem encoding characters such as "é, ç, à", the script was created using Notepad++ with UTF-8 encoding.

How can I avoid this encoding problem?

What encoding should I use in notepad++ ?

Comment: give a shot to "Encode in UTF-8-BOM"

Comment: @burkay, I tried "Encode in UTF-8-BOM", but the problem persists

Comment: then maybe the answer here helps: http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/how-to-specify-charset-encoding-on-liquibase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by using `UTF-8(BOM)` encoding